# React reducer call twice

Tags: reactjs, redux

i am using react and redux for my application. My problem is i receive 2 time my props the first is undefined and the second is ok. So i cannot use the props.

```js
import ...

class Home extends Component {
  
  //some code logic 
  
  render(){
 console.log(this.props.header);
 
 const header = this.props.header;
  
    return (
      <Welcome title={header.title} />
    )
  }

}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    header: _.find(state.header, { 'page': 'accueil' })
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home);
```

console.log give me 2 answer :
   1 / undefined
   2 / Array of obj (that what i need)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property title of undefined

[image]

Comment: Need a little more to go on here. When is `state.header` being set? After an API call?  It might be as simple as adding `if (!this.props.header) return null` to the start of the `render` function, but that might only hide the issue and not fix the cause.

Comment: Yes i calling it from an API. So if i pass it to child it does not work but if i am doing a normal loop inside this component it work well.

Comment: If that's the case, it is not unexpected that it is `undefined` the first time it renders (it hasn't got the data yet).  returning `null` isn't doing a "loop" inside the component, it is saying there is noting to render, which there isn't in the case of the initial render.  You could also return some kind of `Loading` component instead of `null` for a better user experience.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is quite simple. In your case when you define a reducer the initial state would be set to `undefined` which will be returned the first time and later after some processing the date will be returned. So you can do two things

First: set the initial state in reducer

```
var initialState = {
   id: '',
   page: '',
   title: '',
   metaTitle: '',
   subtitle: ''
}
const reducerState = (state = initialState, action) => {

  ......  //Do what you want here
   return state
}
```

Second:  check if the `header.title` is defined in component

```
class Home extends Component {

  //some code logic 

  render(){
 console.log(this.props.header);

 const header = this.props.header;

    return (
      {header.title && <Welcome title={header.title} />}
    )
  }

}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    header: state.header
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home);
```

Comment: Trying your solution got  error    'initialState' is not defined

Comment: change `var intialState = {` to `var initialState = {`

Comment: There was a typo in variable name initialstate, corrected it.

Comment: This still wont work as the `header` prop will still be `undefined` (the `_.find` has nothing to find).  You need to just test for `header`.

Comment: @MichaelPeyper I think it should be just fine without the _find

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri What you have now would work, but the reason for the find (I assume) is that `state.header` in the original post was an array (otherwise find would not have been necessary at all).